# I am trying to make if commands with inputs, how do I make a command like this?

Tags: python, input

```
name = input("What is your name?")
if name = Bob:
    print ("Hi")
```

I am a beginner in python so it would be greatly appreciated if you would give an explanation or simple answer
    -thanks

Comment: Where are you learning python from? There are so many mistakes here. You should really follow a tutorial or something from the very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

```
if name == "Bob":
    print ("Hi")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` for comparison, and string variables should be within quotes:

```
if name == "Bob":
    print ("Hi")
```

Comment: Bob should be within quotes, try with `"Bob"`